# How to format paragraphs like RFCs using gvim?

Tags: vim

I write quite an amount of documents using gvim. I notice that I spend more time in formatting them. I like the RFC format. Trying to optimize, I was looking for commands/macros in gvim to do them efficiently. Has anyone tried RFC like formatting for paragraphs, headers with gvim?

Comment: I assume you [found this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2930) before? you might extend it with your desired features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you  know the appropriate config options for the `par`(1) external program (which has very high chances because I expect this is the program *normally* used to format RFC's), you can set the `'formatprg'` setting to use it

- http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Par_text_reformatter
- http://vimcasts.org/episodes/formatting-text-with-par/ (vimcast)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Sehe. I was not aware of par(1). Let me check it out and the links.